# Getting largest index from tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

My CNN has yielded the following (from `model.predict()`):

```
Tensor(&quot;input_1:0&quot;, shape=(?, 2, 26, 1), dtype=float32)
[9.9952221e-01 2.3613637e-04 1.9953270e-06 1.6922619e-05 2.2012556e-04
 2.4441533e-07 3.5276526e-07 7.4913805e-07 4.0657511e-07 8.7760031e-07]
```

I would like to get the index of the largest value from this numpy array. Right now, I have tried doing this (`x` being the array above):

```
result = x.index(max(x))
```

Instead, this raises an error saying that this data type does not support `.index`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) function:

```
import numpy as np

preds = model.predict(test_data)
pred_class = np.argmax(preds, axis=-1)
```